# Django: def save() in models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, save

I'm trying to add the save-function inside my models.py, but it seems I'm doing something wrong. The user has to type the first- and last-name. Without him or her entering any more data, another field inside my models.py should be filled with a combination from these fields.

models.py:

```
class Coworker(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is this even possible? Thanks for all your help.

Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Please don't. This is redundant data. You can simply calculate it with an annotation, or with a property. By saving it, you make synchronizing a more challenging task.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. Why not generate the `full_name` ad-hoc when you want to display the data?

Comment: Please dont missunderstand: I don't want to use it in an example like the above, rather in combination with let's say an if-else-statement or other things.This was just an example for me to understand, if something like this is even possible.

Comment: If found the official documentation was rather unhelpful in this case.

Comment: @finethen: the more complex the logic is, the more I would lean to do this ad hoc. It will cause a lot of trouble to keep it in sync. Especially since a lot of Django ORM calls, like `.update(..)` do not call `.save(..)` and would thus circumvent updating the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't. This is redundant data. It turns out that keeping data in sync, even on the same database is more challening than it might look at first sight. Django has furthermore several functions like [**`.update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) to update records in the table, but circumventing the `.save()` call.

You can for example use a property that will calculate the `full_name` at runtime at the Django/Python level:

```
class Coworker(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

If you want to be able to filter on the `full_name` for example, you can make an annotation, in this case with [**`Concat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat):

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Coworker.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(
        'first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name',
         output_field=CharField()
    )
).filter(full_name__icontains='some query')
```